# smtb server error in bugzilla

Tags: email, smtp, bugzilla

I'm using Bugzilla 5.0.3 and I can't send email using smtp server
I'm trying the gmail smtp "smtp.gmail.com:465" but it gives me the error

> The new value for smtpserver is invalid: Cannot connect to smtp.gmail.com using port 465.

and when I sue it without the port 465 it keeps giving me the error

> The new value for smtpserver is invalid: Cannot connect to smtp.gmail.com.

what should I do to be able to use my gmail to send emails and solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

the error generally arise if there some problem in your internet connection or some Bugzilla configuration

For Bugzilla SMTP configuration

> mail_delivery_method------------>      SMTP
>
> mailfrom -------------- ------------>   yourgmailid@gmail.com
>
> smtpserver             ------------------------>   smtp.gmail.com
>
> smtp_username       ----------------->      yourgmailid
>
> smtp_password            -----------------> yourgmailidPassword
>
> smtp_ssl                  ---------------------------> on

In Linux System you can also host-name in 
/etc/hosts and /etc/hostname
 if they both are same or not (make them same) 

also check if your firewall is not stopping you to make smtp connection

try to `ping google.com`
if its give not giving any response
 insert few line in 
/etc/resolv.conf

nameserver  8.8.8.8